# Destructuring and reassigning properties with TypeScript in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component that has input parameters. I am trying to use the destructuring assignment on properties object and to reassign the variable to a different name:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { modelValue: isSelected, date1: inputDate1 } = defineProps({
  modelValue: Boolean,
  date1: String
})

console.log(isSelected)

const date1 = 'abc'
console.log(date1)
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isSelected">Selected!</div>
</template>
```

In code above variable `modelValue` is reassigned to `isSelected` and `date1` is reassigned to `inputDate1`.

The code produces 2 problems.

##### During the editing on line `const date1 = 'abc'` error

> Duplicate key 'date1'. May cause name collision in script or template tag. eslintvue/no-dupe-keys

This is a completely false error. If you rewrite the code to the following:

```js
const date2 = 'abc'
console.log(date1)
```

then you'd face another error on line `console.log(date1)`:

> Cannot find name 'date1'. Did you mean 'date2'? ts(2552)

So it's apparent that no other variable exists with same name `date1`. What is the initial problem then? Why is the compiler complaining about the duplicate name?

Furthermore, to add up, the line `console.log(date1)` outputs the correct value during runtime.

##### During the runtime exception/warning is thrown from the template

> [Vue warn]: Property "isSelected" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

I don't see how it's true... The line:

```
console.log(isSelected)
```

outputs the correct value (either `true` or `false`).

So again, I don't understand what the problem is. If I get rid of destructuring variable reassignment then the code works without errors:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { modelValue } = defineProps({
  modelValue: Boolean
})
console.log(modelValue)
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="modelValue">Selected!</div>
</template>
```

`console.log(modelValue)` outputs the same exact value as before.
`console.log(typeof modelValue)` prints `boolean`.
`console.log(typeof isSelected)` also prints `boolean`.
So what's the issue?

Comment: What exactly is giving you that error? Is it the editor/ide?

Comment: 1. editing = ide
2. runtime = browser's console

Comment: _Duplicate key 'date1'. May cause name collision in script or template tag. eslintvue/no-dupe-keys_ In the template, props are auto-unwrapped. So your variable and the prop would conflict. It isn't an issue in the script because they are not auto-unwrapped there.

Comment: Then, a core issue: you can't just destructure props. The props object is reactive, and destructuring a reactive object breaks reactivity. You must use `toRefs()` to convert it to an object of refs, which you _can_ destructure.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes thank you.. But why doesn't `typeof` show that the property is reactive? If you could post your comment as an answer - I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

You can't just destructure props. The props object returned by `defineProps()` is reactive, and destructuring a reactive object breaks the reactivity; the destructured variables will be given the current values of the properties (because the object is a proxy, and only property accesses are monitored). You must use [`toRefs()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs) to convert it to an object of refs, which you can then destructure.

Okay, actually, I lied a bit. ["Reactive props destructure"](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure) (that docs page says the reactivity transform is deprecated, but this specific feature has been split off) is a thing now, which means that in essence the compiler rewrites

```
const { prop: foo } = defineProps({ prop: String })
console.log(foo)
```

to

```
const __props = defineProps({ prop: String })
console.log(__props.prop)
```

Some people like this. Personally, I find it extremely unintuitive and confusing. To each their own.

I find it makes the typing confusing. In the above, `foo` is a string, but is secretly reactive (the only case in the script block of a "bare" reactive primitive, to my knowledge).

---

Simplifying the first code block:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { date1: inputDate1 } = defineProps({
  date1: String
})

const date1 = 'abc'
console.log(date1)
</script>
```

So, you have this error:

> Duplicate key 'date1'. May cause name collision in script or template tag. eslintvue/no-dupe-keys

Props are auto-unwrapped in the template. I.e., you can access them in the same way you can access properties on `window` without explicitly specifying `window.`; they are in the top-level scope.

The props have a prop named `date1`, and the unwrapping means that it will be top-level in the template. You then define a variable also named `date1`, which will also be top-level in the template. These two identifiers can conflict, which is what ESLint is warning about.

Then, your example edit:

```js
const date2 = 'abc'
console.log(date1)
```

And the new error:

> Cannot find name 'date1'. Did you mean 'date2'? ts(2552)

This is because props are only auto-unwrapped in the template, and not in the script. So `date1` is not defined there.

---

> Furthermore, to add up, the line `console.log(date1)` outputs the correct value during runtime.

Well, it will output the value of the prop from when the component was created.
But it is not reactive; and the `console.log()` would not run again, even if it were. (Well, it's partially reactive; see the first section of this answer.)

---

On to the next error:

> [Vue warn]: Property "isSelected" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

I'm afraid I can't reproduce this.

Maybe it was an HMR issue/glitch?

---

I don't know your exact Vue version or config, so I can't say more on specifics, such as the error I could not reproduce. If you want to press that point, add the full code and config of a reproduction to your answer, and preferably a link to a Vue Playground or StackBlitz project or similar.

I made a [Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNUk1vnDAQ/SuuL9lIu3DIpUJslKbKoT20UVP15AuBgXXqL9mG3Qrx3zs2gSW0iXJBeN6b5+eZ19NPxiRdCzSjuSstN5448K25ZopLo60nPbFQk4HUVktygdSLGfqspXmuJ2k4BCWEmSq1cqh00EeyD/2buhAOLpnK0/EW1MeDB2lE4QFPhORcmdYT/8fAntHyAOXvR31ilHQ7qSsQWAyCjI7sePkaIimCeTrr0i31Ds3UvEmenFb4zD50oz62cwH2u/EczTKakYgErBBCH7/GmrctbKd69PSf+pNDmxn+3FtwYDtgdMZ8YRvwI3z38A1O+D+DaL4VyH4D/AFOizZ4HGm3rarQ9oIX3X6JG+Gq+enuTh6Umx4VjAbmEPmM4obC5F57+tnuVXIV+5gacIrTdtc5IaJQDY7fo8w1s9PmexL38qsQLWSEuwcQUHqoMEd7UkHNFdxbbdymDz3kBftWawGF2gZkuAzfSRfridDN5qwX4XOmnrmLXEX1vOIdRoXXaPTci4an3w95ipTIXoQnHPHpY9h3sjCrCI3Ay/nhiMY9Hbw3LkvTslLYhq/jnU0U+FQZmd4gLbWt8lzCrtLyBoedfEQPzi/LCTi5e7T6iKFCkcXOQ39Mmt1ZUBXYkIj3XbtqW169gv65fs7D8BdsQnK/) while testing things. You can play around and view the compiled code.